# How to get vertical line in PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports, export-to-pdf

Using *JasperReports* I have generated a report. It's showing properly in html file.

The problem is when I try to generate PDF with the same JasperPrint I am not getting the Vertical line.

This is the code i have written.

```
 String fileName = new Date().getTime() + ""; 
 byte[] bytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
 response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\""+fileName+".pdf\"");
 response.setContentType("application/pdf");
 response.setContentLength(bytes.length);           
 ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
```

Comment: Are you getting report properly?I guess only Vertical line is not visible.

Comment: @TAsk Yes, I am getting the report properly. The vertical line is not coming.